Custom error push with spring mvc and rollbar
I have a spring boot application and we are using rollbar as error tracking system. As I read here https://rollbar.com/blog/introducing-our-new-java-spring-error-monitoring-sdk/
the rollbar sends automatically all spring errors. The challenge we are facing is for api responses with non 2xx codes the error is sent to rollbar which we dont want for example 4xx errors can be excluded.
Can anyone help here how can we achieve this? I tried with having custom exception resolver but didnt get through it.
